# jQueryUI Datepicker prev and next icons not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have incorporated a jquery datepicker into my application however no matter what theme I select the prev/next icons do not show. I have used a different version of the jquery-ui.js too. I have tried a couple of items I had seen previously posted like - using 'hideIfNoPrevNext' or

```
 $( ".date" ).datepicker( "option", "changeMonth", true );
```

One suggestion that I cannot find is where the 'image' folder is located. I have looked in the jquery-ui.js and the theme.css.

In my code I reference the files in this order:

```
 <link href="js/ui_1.10.4_themes_smoothness_jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery_ui_1.11.4_jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in the theme it references the icons as:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
.ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-error .ui-icon,
.ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When downloading [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/) you should get a zip file that will contain the images folder you are looking for. These will need to be including with your project in order for the icons to properly show up. Including these depends on the type of web server you are using to serve your files.

Answer (score 0):

who reading this question, 
If you use this dateime picker
http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

You add this option: bootcssVer : 3

```
 $( ".date" ).datepicker( "option", "changeMonth", true, **"bootcssVer" : 3** );
```

The icon will show!!!

Comment: What are those `**` doing there? The link you shared is dead.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the text-indent was set to `-99999px` and by patching it to be `0px` I fixed my issue.

Comment: The icons didn't come! I got the text 'prev' and "next' instead of icons.